# Free subgroups of the Hilbert modular group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-forms

Let $F$ be a real quadratic field with ring of integers $\mathfrak{o}_F$. What is known about free subgroups of the Hilbert modular group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o}_F)$? Does it contain free subgroups that are not cyclic and are not contained in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$? For example, assuming $2$ is innert in $F$,  is the principal congruence subgroup of level $2$  ever free?

Comment: By the way, the proper way to deal with the discovery that someone answered the question that you literally asked, only to discover that you did not ask the question that you had intended to ask, is NOT to write a comment saying "I intended to ask..." and then change your question. Instead, you should graciously accept the answer to the question you *did* ask, and then ask a new question in a new post.

Comment: Except for "moral" reasons, I don't really see a problem with changning my question in this case, as the first answer was pointing out a rather trivial case, which could also have been done  in a comment first. Why create  two posts with essentially the same question?

Comment: There are practical reasons as well, such as crediting someone for their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll modify the question again, but clearly it contains free subgroups not contained in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, namely conjugates of free subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

No subgroup of **finite index** is free: indeed each $\Gamma$ as in the question is an irreducible lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ (use the two embeddings $F\to\mathbf{R}$) and such a group is known to be just-infinite by work of Margulis: every normal subgroup, other than $\{1\}$ and $\{\pm 1\}$ has finite index. An easier way to prove this is to use that $\Gamma$ has an infinite solvable subgroup of exponential growth (the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $\Gamma$: use Dirichlet's unit theorem to prove this).

$\Gamma$ also contains finitely generated free subgroups that are Zariski-dense (in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$) and hence not virtually conjugate into $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. I think this follows from results of Margulis-Soifer.

Comment: Thanks. This is already very helpful, as I was most interested in finite-index subgroups. (I suppose You meant to write SL_2(R) \times SL_2(R) in the second paragraph). I am missing some of the background to understand all the words in your answer. To be sure, in the end you use that free groups on at least two generators admit infinite index normal subgroups?

Comment: Yes, and also virtually free groups do. Also, virtually free groups have $2^{\aleph_0}$ normal subgroups while just-infinite finitely generated groups only have countably many. But in a second thought, the existence of non-virtually-abelian solvable subgroups is a much simpler way to prove that these $\Gamma$ are not virtually free. Still there are other useful ways to see this. For instance, the virtual cohomological dimension of $\Gamma$ is 3.